# What is the best practice in blackberry development for reaching the widest range of smart phones?

Tags: blackberry

I am wondering if anyone out there has experience writing application for blackberry smart phones.  In particular, I am wondering how they get around the myriad permutations of model number/carrier and OS.

Is there a recommended approach on how to write your code so that it targets the widest range of smart phones?

Are there compiler switches that can be used to target code for particular model numbers?

Comment: Good question, I also would like to know any information about popularity of BB devices and carriers!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Tips for wide range devices

The question is: how to write code that will handle different RIM OS, carriers and device models? In code that will depends on available/deprecated API, in workflow about handling carriers features and characteristics of device.

First of all, read [How To - Develop applications for different BlackBerry Device Software versions and BlackBerry smartphone models](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800783/How_To_-_Develop_applications_for_different_BlackBerry_Device_Software_versions_and_BlackBerry_smartphone_models.html?nodeid=1734478&vernum=0)

### Wide range RIM OS support

[StackOverflow - Which BlackBerry OS version to target for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437044/which-blackberry-os-version-to-target-for) - to be short, my choice is RIM OS 4.5

Tips for 4.7 - 4.6 - 4.5 - ? support:

- navigation, use accelerometer and touchscreen, but don't forget about trackball and menu
- borders, there are no BorderFactory in 4.5 and earlier
- background, there are no Background in 4.5 and earlier
- transparency, there is no Graphics.setGlobalAlpha(alpha) in 4.5 and earlier
- multimedia, different formats are supported on differen OS and phones

See also
[Blackberry - How to add border to BasicEditField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135349/blackberry-how-to-add-border-to-basiceditfield)
[Setting background and font colors for RichTextField, TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431189/setting-background-and-font-colors-for-richtextfield-textfield)
[Skinning Blackberry Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445953/blackberry-user-interface-design-customizable-ui/1450719#1450719)
[What Is - Supported audio formats](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/1089414/What_Is_-_Supported_audio_formats.html?nodeid=1187763&vernum=0)
[Support - Playing audio pauses Media app on BlackBerry CDMA smartphones](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/1089414/Support_-_Playing_audio_in_an_application_pauses_the_Media_application_on_BlackBerry_smartphones_running_on_the_CDMA_network.html?nodeid=1376897&vernum=0)
[How To - Record Audio on a BlackBerry smartphone](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/1089414/How_To_-_Record_audio_on_a_BlackBerry_smartphone.html?nodeid=1311883&vernum=0)

### Carrier support

I have no statistical information about BlackBerry carriers. But lets see what are those carrier features we can meet:

- if we use carrier network resources, carrier controlls all network configuration. That means on ex. we may have no UDP, max. transfer file size about 3 Mb, and we will have to config APN settings
- also, carrier and device combination defines what GPS type is accessible. And for Verizone, there is a special signing process to access GPS.

See also
[What Is - Restricted ports](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Restricted_ports.html?nodeid=1449563&vernum=0)
[What Is - Network Diagnostic Tool](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Network_Diagnostic_Tool.html?nodeid=1450596&vernum=0)
[How To - Determine when to route data](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/How_To_-_Determine_when_to_route_data.html?nodeid=1181674&vernum=0) 
[What Is - Different ways to make an HTTP or socket connection](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_make_an_HTTP_or_socket_connection.html?nodeid=826935&vernum=0)
[How To - Specify APN information for a direct TCP connection](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/How_To_-_Specify_APN_information_for_a_direct_TCP_connection.html?nodeid=1265025&vernum=0) 
[What Is - Best practices for designing GPS applications for BlackBerry CDMA smartphones](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800703/What_Is_-_Best_practices_for_designing_GPS_applications_for_BlackBerry_smartphones_operating_on_CDMA_networks.html?nodeid=1446048&vernum=0)
[What Is - The BlackBerry smartphone models and their corresponding GPS capabilities](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800703/What_Is_-_The_BlackBerry_smartphone_models_and_their_corresponding_GPS_capabilities.html?nodeid=1371352&vernum=0)
[What Is - Verizon GPSSettings signing requirement](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800703/What_Is_-_Verizon_GPSSettings_signing_requirement.html?nodeid=1365068&vernum=0)

### Different devices

Things which may help support set of devices:

- use flexible, elastic UI elements, change size and layout according to screen size
- use several graphic resources sets of different size
- control font type and size
- before use camera, check if it's available

See also
[What Is - Compatibility mode on touch screen BlackBerry smartphones](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800719/What_Is_-_Compatibility_mode_on_touch_screen_BlackBerry_smartphones.html?nodeid=1487544&vernum=0)
[What Is - Image formats used in BlackBerry applications](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800608/What_Is_-_Image_formats_used_in_BlackBerry_applications.html?nodeid=800342&vernum=0)

### Building several RIM OS

There are [preprocessor directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383277/using-preprocessor-directives-in-blackberry-jde-plugin-for-eclipse), but I prefer to use [BB Ant tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs), copy/delete all platform version diff (code, resources) and target appropriate rapc directory from build task.

See also
[How To - Use the preprocessor](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/1407892/How_To_-_Use_the_preprocessor.html?nodeid=1487658&vernum=0)

Comment: Another link: http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800901/What_Is_-_Supported_versions_of_Java_for_different_BlackBerry_JDE_versions.html?nodeid=1313614&vernum=0

Answer (score 0):

As part of development process one can code for all possible Blackberry Smart phones using the concept of [Preprocessors](http://berrytutorials.blogspot.in/2009/11/coding-for-multiple-blackberry-devices.html)

You will need to create separate builds for each OS version though.