# What minimum BlackBerry OS should I develop for?

Tags: blackberry

I am developing a Netflix application for BlackBerry mobile devices. I need to make a decision as to the minimum OS version that I should develop for - depending on which I choose will have some design impacts (such as what browser field classes I can use, etc.)

What it comes down to is..should I support anything lower than OS 5.0?

Comment: you can go for O.S. 4.5 and above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say 4.5 and newer. see also:
[OS - What market share do each of the BlackBerry models have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868567/what-market-share-do-each-of-the-blackberry-models-have)
[OS - Which BlackBerry OS version to target for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437044/which-blackberry-os-version-to-target-for)
[OS - What is the best practise in blackberry for reaching the widest range of smart phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540550/what-is-the-best-practise-in-blackberry-development-for-reaching-the-widest-range)

Answer (score 3):

I think there a few things to consider.  First off, you need to have a clear vision of what you are hoping to achieve - features/functionality. Then evaluate the various API revisions, and determine which API level will provide the facilities needed to achieve your goals.  Depending on the outcome of this, you may have to revise your goals.  Maybe even consider using a lower API version, rolling out with a reduced feature set to help get your foot into the market, then in parallel be working on the full bells and whistles release utilizing a higher API version.  But most importantly, you need to evaluate your market.  The question becomes: "Does your target API provide you will enough of a potential market for your app?"  But sometimes it becomes a difficult juggle, especially if you embrace the concept of "Build it and they will come" and you develop your app for the bleeding edge - waiting for the masses to arrive.  You need to be sure to have the coverage in place (ie. financial, and political if you are in a large corporate environment) to survive until the day arrives.  If you haven't already, you may want to look into becoming a Blackberry Alliance member.  Also, don't be afraid to engage the major carriers in your market and push them a bit.  They should be able to give you a bit of visibility into handset/platform penetration.  Evaluate all of the variables both technical and business plan, and document it - the answer will come to you.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

RIM have created an official page with statistics that help you figure out the answer to this question: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/choosingtargetos.jsp

For example, as of November 2010, OS 5.0+ made up less than 50% of the market share of all active Blackberry devices, but OS 5.0+ accounts for 75% of free app downloads and 86% of paid app downloads from App World.

Answer (score 1):

ON the basis of API similarities and supports i can divide os range like this

(A).<4.2

(B). 4.2< and <5.0

(c). 5.0

Answer (score 0):

We deploy to 4.3, 4.7, and 5.0 with our app and that covers almost every in-market device being used today.  There may be a few people still running 4.2 but not many.