# Developing for multiple versions of BlackBerry OS

Tags: blackberry

What do I need to know before developing for multiple versions of the BlackBerry OS? Any good resources?

Comment: seems like a duplication... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540550/what-is-the-best-practise-in-blackberry-development-for-reaching-the-widest-range I would suggest you to tag a questions, so it would be easier to find out duplicates before posting ;)

Comment: @Max, good point. I'm voting to close. Also, I wasn't aware of the os-version tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These links should provide the required resources:

- [Appropriate version of the JDE](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800738/800901/What_Is_-_Appropriate_version_of_the_BlackBerry_JDE.html?nodeid=1287169&vernum=0)
- [Developing for different versions in the Knowledge Center](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800783/How_To_-_Develop_applications_for_different_BlackBerry_Device_Software_versions_and_BlackBerry_smartphone_models.html?nodeid=1734478&vernum=0)
- [Preprocessor](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/1407892/How_To_-_Use_the_preprocessor.html?nodeid=1487658&vernum=0)
- [How to retrieve the BlackBerry Software Version](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800620/How_To_-_Retrieve_the_BlackBerry_Device_Software_version.html?nodeid=800529&vernum=0)