# Dynamic Editfield

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-editfield

I have `EditField` and use background image..i want to create dynamic `EditField`

so i want to dynamic height `EditField`but fix width

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135349/blackberry-how-to-add-border-to-basiceditfield

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://us.blackberry.com/devjournals/resources/journals/jul_2005/creating_textbox_field.jsp, it provides details on creating one.